# Getting error Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am getting error while running spring-boot application.

```
2020-01-30 10:33:19.294  WARN 11168 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mailManagerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2020-01-30 10:33:19.294  INFO 11168 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-01-30 10:33:19.309  INFO 11168 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-01-30 10:33:19.434 ERROR 11168 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

Description:

Field `jdbcTemplate` in `com.service.el.microservice.user.UserRepository` required a bean of type `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` in your configuration.

But the issue is I have already defined *@Bean* for *JdbcTemplate* in the configuration.
I am using java 1.8, spring-boot: 2.2.4

Can anybody helps me out to get rid of this issue?

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class someclass {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(this.dbDriver);
        datasource.setUrl(this.dbURL);
        datasource.setUsername(this.dbUserName);
        datasource.setPassword(this.dbPassword);
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        //return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundle getQueryResourceBundle() {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("query");
        return rb;
    }
}
```

This is the class where JDBCtemplate has been used

```
@Repository
public class AutoEventRepository {

    @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutoEventRepository.class);

    public List<AutoEventVO> getExistPielData(String esn) {
        try{
            List<AutoEventVO> List = jdbcTemplate.query(resourceBundle.getString(AutoEventQueryConstant.GET_EXIST_PIEL_DATA),
            new Object[] { esn }, new existPIELMapper());
            return List;
        }
```

Comment: Please add the full error. The fact that you have an `@Configiuration` with a `JdbcTemplate` doesn't mean that configuraiton is used. Also Spirng Boot provides a `JdcbTemplate` out-of-the-box so not sure why you need to add one yourself. Looks like you are working around Spring Boot instead of working with it.

Comment: Yes true @M.Deinum, spring boot do that by itself. Not sure why i am getting that. But any way i have updated the full error in question

Comment: Can you add code snippet as well? Thanks.

Comment: @YogeenLoriya i have updated with code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The class containing the

> @Bean JdbcTemplate

method should have

> @Configuration

annotation so that during component scan spring can crate bean of JdbcTemplate.

Change your code with below snippet and try again.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(this.dbDriver);
        datasource.setUrl(this.dbURL);
        datasource.setUsername(this.dbUserName);
        datasource.setPassword(this.dbPassword);
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean("jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean("resourceBundle")
    public ResourceBundle resourceBundle() {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("query");
        return rb;
    }
}
```

Comment: @rakes I have added code snippet, please try with that.

Comment: I have updated with the class, where jdbctemplate has been used